# HighMap - why the data doesn't display after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am using Highmap to create a map and want to display data with different charts after clicking (or hover) on a part of the map.

Here is the example (I don't want to use Google Spreadsheet for data, I want to use json data) [My Example](http://jsfiddle.net/laravinchi/8qGpF/1/)

The Highmap example is here [HighMap](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges). (Using Google Spreadsheet)

If anyone can help to come out this, ll be helpful.

Here is code snippet

```
       Highcharts.each(Highcharts.maps, function (mapPoint) {
            var key = mapPoint.code,
                i = $.inArray(key, keys);
            options.series[0].data.push(Highcharts.extend({
                value : parseFloat(percent[i]),
                name : names[i],
                key: key
            }, mapPoint));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the question, but will try to answer. In general, you have a chart, but your series data doesn't contain values, add them and will work. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qGpF/2/).

```
                series: [{
                    name: 'Random data',  
                    data: [{
                        color: '#0200D0',
                        name : 'A',
                        y: 30
                    }, {
                        color: '#C40401',
                        name : 'B',
                        y: 20
                    }],
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> {point.percentage:.1f}%'
                    }
                }],
```

Of course, these values will be always fixed. In your case I would use some AJAX to get JSON in `pointClick()` function, then display data from JSON on a chart.

Comment: Yes, the json data is coming from the server and on click it ll update the chart.

Comment: Here as an example ,I use the json data in the same JS file.

Comment: So what is the question? Before creating chart, call AJAX to your server, then inside callback of AJAX create such chart.

Comment: Well facing problem in showing data on 2nd window highchart.

Comment: Not able to find out , no error in console also. It s just nothing displaying, eventually I was trying map in SVG format then shifted to this one.

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks for your effort. But I didn't want what you suggested .

Comment: Maybe update your question with better description of the problem?